# Offshore windfarm and real life effects on ocean fish

Tags: emf

An offshore windfarm is being proposed which will consist of 170 wind turbines that will produce 1100MW of power. The offshore substations will utilize 15 miles of export cable.
Part of their presentation is an assumption that there will be no EMF emitted by the export cables because the phases are balanced.

This statement is being made to quiet any opposition related to local fish sensing the EMF and being affected. There are dolphins, sharks, skates and many other species that traverse the area.

I have looked at some submarine cable specifications for what might be used and do not see adequate shielding to totally reduce the emissions or a “twisting rate” of the individual phase cables (which would also help reduce EMF.)

Can you please add your comments to this real problem? I have already seen questions posed by windfarm trouble shooters citing unbalanced voltages at the turbine generators.

Comment: Context: https://tethys.pnnl.gov/sites/default/files/summaries/SEER-Educational-Research-Brief-Electromagnetic-Field-Effects-on-Marine-Life.pdf

Comment: if the currents are not balanced, where is the difference going?

Comment: Adam's link suggests that the very limited range that EMF extends from undersea cables is insignificant enough that it doesn't have an obviously negative effect on animals. You think it does, so maybe asking I'm biology stack exchange would be more productive.

Comment: Is this an AC or DC interconnector? The difference is that between insignificant and zero, respectively. Is this the first undersea power cable ever to be laid, or are there many many thousands of km already in the sea all over the world?

Comment: Only 15 miles of cable is almost certainly AC.  DC is used for very long undersea cables, but losses from AC would be insignificant over that distance.

Comment: Looking for potential problems in isolation is disingenuous. Given how despised nuclear power seems to be, the alternatives are what? Offshore wind, onshore wind, onshore solar, hydro, or fossil fuels, right? Presumably offshore wind is proposed because it is most economically viable renewable in circumstances? I'm not sure what other renewables are feasible in your area. But just consider that one alternative is getting this power from a fossil plant. If you think fish have it bad with a wind farm, just wait till you read what fossil plant pollution does to fish.

Comment: In other words, even if the cables did bad things to fish - and they don't really - then a fossil plant alternative is orders of magnitude worse and it has a much wider-reaching effects. And if the offshore wind farm has other onshore renewable alternatives, then are there any investors willing to put the money into it? Consider cost of land and power transmission in addition to the cost of operating the wind farm.

Answer (score 2):

There's no real problem with balance here – because unbalanced loads lead to losses and heat all over the generation, distribution, and transformation systems, both the energy companies and large industrial consumers are very self-motivated to keep phases balanced. There's no problem at all if these power plants are connected via a DC interconnect (because there's only one field).

I have no idea what kind of cabling is used, but usually power transmission cables *are* somewhat shielded, both implicitly by the steel armour that typically protects them mechanically, and explicitly by materials and construction. So, I'd say unless you have simulation models or proper measurements that prove your cable type is insufficiently shielded, I'd assume the fact that your wind park has got to get legal approval to make large constructions in nature (at least here in Europe, that's a harsh requirement), my bet is that they are absolutely safe to be left alone next to fish. If you have questions, ask the environmental protection authorities of your country; they have to approve this park, and thus, at a point where the future operator holds public presentations, they very likely have at the very least preliminary requests for approval, including extensive documentation of the potential environmental dangers, and the mitigations they are implementing, as well as compensatory measures taken for interfering with nature.

Talking about fish: the fish here live in salt water. If *anything* attenuates electrical fields, it's conductive media. So, on that front you're pretty safe.

But that's not all there is to EMF, but honestly, this topic has been dealt with in scientific studies for *so many existing offshore wind park* already that it's very likely that there's even existing scientific models for your very specific type of coast.

I'd generally also recommend comparing the effect of 25 years (this is a safe lower estimate for the time until these things need to get replaced) of carbon emission reduction due to the availability of wind energy within your regional power mix on global climate change and comparing that to the hypothetical negative influence on the local fauna.

Comment: Marcus, second paragraph, first sentence: did you mean "armour" rather than "armature". I'm a long-term admirer of your standard of English.

Comment: ha! Indeed, I mistranslated German "Armierung"

Comment: And thanks for the compliment, @Transistor :)